# How to configure Zend 2 on a hosting server?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I created a virtual host: www.attila-naghi.ro in the xampp. I put my project there and it works perfectly. Now I want to put it online, on a hosting server. I observed that my css and js are not loaded and if I access the controllers, I get the 404. This is the [URL](http://attila-naghi.com/). Can anyone help me? thx

This is my module.config.php file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Zend Framework (http://framework.zend.com/)
 *
 * @link      http://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication for the canonical source repository
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2005-2014 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
 */

return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'home' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type' => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route' => '[:controller[/:action]][/:param1]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*'
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'action' => 'index',
                                '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                               // 'param1' => 'tralala'
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'abstract_factories' => array(
            'Zend\Cache\Service\StorageCacheAbstractServiceFactory',
            'Zend\Log\LoggerAbstractServiceFactory',
        ),
        'aliases' => array(
            'translator' => 'MvcTranslator',
        ),
    ),
    'translator' => array(
        'locale' => 'en_US',
        'translation_file_patterns' => array(
            array(
                'type'     => 'gettext',
                'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
                'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Application\Controller\Index'          => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
            'Application\Controller\Create'         => 'Application\Controller\CreateController',
            'Application\Controller\Blog'           => 'Application\Controller\BlogController',
            'Application\Controller\Portofolio'     => 'Application\Controller\PortofolioController',
            'Application\Controller\User'           => 'Application\Controller\UserController',
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'base_path' => 'http://www.attila-naghi.com/',
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
    // Placeholder for console routes
    'console' => array(
        'router' => array(
            'routes' => array(
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the Skeleton Application you can see the `/public` directory. The contents of those are supposed to go into whatever your server's public directory is. For example, for servers with cPanel it's the `public_html`. Other hosting servers may have `www`, or something else.

I've recently uploaded a zend skeleton app doing exactly as above and it worked perfectly. If you wonder what to do with the original (Skeleton's) directory `/public` - I left it along with my `public_html` but you can remove it as it is empty.