# Deploy on Shared Web Host

Tags: apache, .htaccess, zend-framework2

I have a simple question but I just can't find a straightforward answer anywhere.

I'm not very familiar with apache .htaccess and now I should deploy a ZF2 app on a web host that doesn't allow me to change the website root folder.

I have a standard project structure so my `index.php` file is located inside the `/public` folder, like this:

```
www.mydomain.com

root/ <--- I can't set root to /public folder
    /config
        ...
    /module
        ...
    /public
        .htaccess
        index.php
        ...
    /vendor
        ...
    ...
```

This is from the ZF2 skeleton app.

Please I need a workaround, I'm sure this is a pretty common problem that many ZF2 developers already tackled. I think I should add a .htaccess file to `/root` but I don't know how to write one that would work in this case.

As always any help is much appreciated,

Dan

Comment: Have you followed the [Apache configuration instructions](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/installation.html#apache-setup)?

Comment: @AlexP I cannot set a virtual host either since is a cheap Web Hosting server I want to use to deploy my app. I just have a root folder and I can't configure anything.

Comment: I recently answered to the [same question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880038/how-to-configure-zend-2-on-a-hosting-server/27881224#27881224

Comment: @developer10 just finished reading it. What if your host doesn't have a public_html (or similar) folder? This appears to be my case. My own answer handles that case too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make this work you have to take everything from the `/public` folder and put it inside your web root. The file `index.php` from the skeleton app must be edited to take account of its new position.

First remove the line:

```
chdir(dirname(__DIR__));
```

Because its purpose is to set the current directory to the web root which we are already inside.

Second you have to either:

Replace the line `require 'init_autoloader.php'` with `require 'vendor/autoload.php'` (if using composer).

**OR**

Inside your `.htaccess` set the `ZF2_PATH` env variable to where zf2 is installed on your server:

```
#First line of your .htaccess
SetEnv ZF2_PATH path/to/zf2
```

Now it should be working.

### Make it better

With the above setup you'll have to put all your public folders inside the web root. If you, like me, don't like that just continue reading.

You can put your public folders (e.g., `/js`, `/css`) inside `/public` (`index.php` and `.htaccess` still need to be in the root) by simply telling zf2 your new `base_path`. This is what is used by the `basePath()` view helper inside your view scripts. You simply need to add the following to your config:

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'base_path' => './public',
),
```

And the `basePath()` view helper will output the correct urls.

### Make it even better

The last problem with this setup is that your app files are accessible from the web. To fix this I put everything I want to hide inside the `/private` folder. You end up with a project structure similar to this:

```
/root
    /private
        /config
        /data
        /module
        /vendor
        .htaccess     <-- You have to create this one
        composer.json
        composer.lock <-- Created by composer after install
        composer.phar
    /public
        /css
        /js
    .htaccess
    index.php
```

Inside the `/private` folder you have to create a new `.htaccess` file and put this line inside it:

```
Deny from all
```

This makes everything inside the folder not accessible from the web.

With this change you have broken your app. Infact inside `/private/config/application.config.php` you have to adjust the `module_paths` config:

```
'module_listener_options' => array(
    'module_paths' => array(
        './module',
        './vendor',
    ),
),
```

You have to prepend `/private` to the paths:

```
'module_listener_options' => array(
    'module_paths' => array(
        './private/module',
        './private/vendor',
    ),
),
```

This will make your app run once again. Now you can deploy your ZF2 apps to shared web hosts and retain a clean project structure.